# Can't install git and openssh-client - "held broken packages" and "no installation candidate"

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I am trying to install git on Ubuntu 14 with the following code

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

I get this output :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
       Recommends: ssh-client
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I am trying to install ssh-client by the following code:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
```

then get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openssh-client is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openssh-client' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Can you add the full output of `sudo apt-get update` and `apt-policy git liberror-perl openssh-client` to your question please?

Comment: Ubuntu 14 doesn't exist. You mean 14.04, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Go to the Ubuntu Software Center.

Type in "Muon Package Manager" and install it.

Open Muon Package Manager and type in "openssh-client".

Click on "openssh-client" in the window and mark it for installation.

Now click "Apply Changes".

It should bring up any dependencies you need. Just click ok to install those dependencies.

OR BETTER YET...

Type in "git" in Muon Package Manager and let it do the work for you. Just click ok to install the dependencies it come up with.

Hope this helps,